# Pigeonhole Principle: Showing that there are at least two holes with the distance between their centres less than $10\sqrt{2}~\text{cm}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I'm having trouble regarding the application of the Pigeonhole Principle. I understand $f:A \to B$ but I don't know how to apply it in questions that require it. Example:

Ten bullets are all shot on a square target of $900~\text{cm}^2$. The statement is: If there are $10$ disjoint holes which are entirely on the target, then there are at least $2$ of them with the distance between their centres less than $10\sqrt{2}~\text{cm}$.

Comment: Hint. Can you think of a way to divide the target into $9$ small pieces? What could you conclude?

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you. How did you know to divide the target into 9 pieces specifically?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @discombobulator With the pigeonhole principle hint and $10$ items, $9$ bins seemed natural. Then when I say the $900$ square cm area I was pretty sure I was on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the square into nine $100$ cm$^2$ squares. By the pigeonhole principle, one of the squares contains at least two holes, and the maximal distance between any two points in the same square is $10\sqrt 2$ cm.

Comment: So the statement would then be true? Since the maximum distance between two bullets is 10sqrt(2) in one square?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it